# Integer partitions comparisons

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that the number of integer partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts is the same as the number of integer partitions of $n$ where the largest part is of size $k$.

Comment: Are you asking us to prove? What did you try?

Comment: I'm currently just working with conjugation facts such as if a partition has largest part k its conjugate and that conjugation is always one-to-one but am struggling with using that to form a proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking at Young diagrams.  They are ways of drawing partitions and one can use them to give a very intuitive proof of this fact.

Comment: I was trying to use a Ferrers diagram to explain it but got stuck. I tried to use the idea of conjugation but ended up more confused.

Comment: A Ferrers diagram is essentially the same as a Young diagram.  I think you have the right idea.  For a Ferrers diagram, the number of rows is the number of parts of the partition and the number of columns is the size of the largest part.  Conjugation interchanges these.

Comment: Wouldn't conjugation just make them both the same size? Is that really enough to prove it? And that doesn't stand for all numbers does it?

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it takes a turn of the head to get a better perspective.

Comment: A bit obscure, but I rather like it. +1